# Show Flex mobile app in Whatsapp gallery button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I would like to know how could i include an application made in Flex mobile to be included in the list when you click on Share button or even when you are in the Whatsapp application, and click on the gallery icon.

```
I do not know where i can get such functionality.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use [native extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html). You have to build an Android SDK Class, where you implement a [share indent](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/)
It is really hard for the first time, if you're not familiar with both platforms, so consider it well!